# How do you Prevent Eclipse Crashing when Switching Workspaces

Tags: eclipse, crash, workspace

I'm trying to switch to a new workspace in Eclipse, but no matter what I do the GUI closes and hangs at the console. There is no debug output or errors messages.

Ok, this can't be a bug in Eclipse, so what do I need to fix on my system to get it working? I'm running on Ubuntu 10.10, the eclipse version is listed:

```
Eclipse SDK
Version: 3.5.2
Build id: M20100211-1343
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: Disable "Assistive Technologies" in the *System*->*Preferences* menu.

You can read more about it in the [related bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326857).

Comment: Have you got any solution for Windows?